# How to view GIT history for multiple files or folders and subfolders?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a need to view history for a list of files and or subfolders. Within Visual Studio, I can view the history for the entire repository under Git's "Manage Branches" function. I can also select a file from Visual Studio's "Solution Explorer" but I am unable to select multiple files or a particular folder and its subfolders. I can navigate through a GIT repository using a browser and use the "History" function which shows the entire folder but not its subfolders. Is there a way to do multiple files or folders?

Comment: It would seem that use is far enough from the beaten path that nobody's bothered automating it yet. You can trivially get very close from the command line, just supply multiple paths to `git log -m --oneline -- this.file that/folder whatever`, it's only if you want rename/copy tracking that you have to do them one by one.